# Polymorphism - Having Trouble Printing a Method in Java

Tags: java, return, polymorphism, private

I'm having trouble with my code. So I have a GeoFig object and a Circle that extends GeoFig. GeoFig contains private fields such as area, radius, and circumference. GeoFig also contains methods setting and getting these fields. I tried to create a Circle object and instantiate the get methods, but they do not work. Any advice? Here is my code below:

```
abstract public class GeoFig {

    private double radius;
    private double area;
    private double circumference;

    public void setRadius(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return this.radius;
    }

    public void setCircArea(double radius){
        this.area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI;
    }

    public double getCircArea(){
        return this.area;
    }

    public void setCircumference(double radius){
        circumference = 2*this.radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public double getCircumference(){
        return this.circumference;
    }

    abstract String getMetrics();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Circle circ = new Circle(2);
        circ.getRadius();
    }
}

public class Circle extends GeoFig {

    public Circle(double radius) {
        setRadius(radius);
        setCircArea(radius);
        setCircumference(radius);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMetrics() {
        return "Object of class Circle " +
            "\nRadius:" + getRadius() +
            "\nArea: " + getCircArea() + 
            "\nCircumference: " + getCircumference();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work as in, if I try to run the program, nothing displays.

Comment: I don't see any `System.out.println` statements.

Comment: Wait, when I did cir.getRadius(); is that supposed to be inside System.out.println()??

Comment: @noobforce if it's resolved, please pick an answer =)

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me. It prints `2.0`

```
abstract class GeoFig {

private double radius;
private double area;
private double circumference;

    public void setRadius(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public double getRadius(){
        return this.radius;
    }

    public void setCircArea(double radius){
        this.area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI;
    }
    public double getCircArea(){
    return this.area;
    }

    public void setCircumference(double radius){
        circumference = 2*this.radius * Math.PI;
    }
    public double getCircumference(){
        return this.circumference;
    }

    abstract String getMetrics();


    public static void main(String[] args){
        test circ = new test(2);
        System.out.println(circ.getRadius()); }
    }






public class test extends GeoFig {

public test(double radius){
    setRadius(radius);
    setCircArea(radius);
    setCircumference(radius);
}

@Override
public String getMetrics(){
    return "Object of class Circle " +
            "\nRadius:" + getRadius() +
            "\nArea: " + getCircArea() + 
            "\nCircumference: " + getCircumference();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a method to display the contents of the object your trying to create for example. Create a ToSTRING method to see the contents of the object.

public void display() {

```
double radius = getRadius() ;
double area= getArea() ;
double circumference= getCircumference() ;
 System.out.println("Radius" + radius + "Area" + area + "Circumference" + circumference) ;
```

} 
 If your using Eclipse  on Windows control +alt s than you can create a ToSTRING method. Mac Command + alt+ s. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to print out the result, try

```
System.out.println(circ.getRadius());
```

instead of

```
circ.getRadius();
```

The problem with what you are currently doing is that it gets the radius but does nothing with that value - you need to tell it to print the value of the radius after getting it.